# Add message to formtastic semantic error block

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

If there are semantic errors in the form (mostly from external API), I'd like to add an explanatory message, like so:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @order, :url => checkout_purchase_url, :html => {:class => 'payment'}, :wrapper_html => { :class => "field" }  do |f| %>
<% if f.has_errors? %>
    <p>There were errors that prevented your order from being submitted.  If you need assistance, please contact us toll-free at <strong>1-800-555-5555</strong>.</p>
    <%= f.semantic_errors %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, `has_errors?` is a protected method.  Is there a way that I can do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as hard as I thought.  I fixed it by checking for errors on the object instead of the form:

```
<% if @object.errors.any? %>
    <p>There were errors that prevented your order from being submitted.  If you need assistance, please contact us toll-free at <strong>1-800-555-5555</strong>.</p>
    <%= f.semantic_errors %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for those who viewed.

Answer (score 4):

If you have nested attributes you won't see any errors associated with them.  To ensure you get all base errors and any nested attributes errors.  Make sure your model contains:

```
validates_presence_of :nested_object
validates_associated :nested_object
```

and in your form:

```
f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's an alternative approach if you want to show similarly helpful messages on each field:

```
= f.label :title
- if f.object.errors.any?
 .error = f.object.errors[:title].flatten.join(' and ')
= f.text_field :title
```

This gives a nicely formatted and easily-styled list of errors for each field. (You can use semantic_errors instead of object.errors if you prefer, same result.)